# How to play video .mp4 ios7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

**I cant play the video because i have this notification  error:**

```
    - (void)playbackFinished:(NSNotification*)notification {
        NSNumber* reason = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey];
        switch ([reason intValue]) {

            case MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackError:{
                **NSLog(@"playbackFinished. Reason: Playback Error");**
                [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                                      delay:0
                                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                                 animations:^{

                                     [m_player.view setAlpha:0];

                                 }
                                 completion:^(BOOL finished){

                                     [m_player.view removeFromSuperview];
                                     m_player = nil;
                                 }];
            }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }


 }
```

Any help is appreciated thanks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find out *why* you're getting a playback error so then you can figure out what needs to be done in order to solve the issue.

Looking at the answers to [this closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352870/how-to-get-an-error-description-when-playback-fails-on-mpmovieplayercontroller), you'll see this code snippet:

```
    NSError *mediaPlayerError = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"];
    if (mediaPlayerError) 
    {
        NSLog(@"playback failed with error description: %@", [mediaPlayerError localizedDescription]);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"playback failed without any given reason");
    }
```

Add these lines to your MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackError case and you may figure out what's really up with your app.  Good luck!

Comment: I have this error now..

playback failed with error description: The operation could not be completed

What can i do? =(