# iOS 8 MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification not working

Tags: ios8, mpmovieplayercontroller

I used Xcode 6 with iOS 8 SDK.

If the video can't played, when starting MPMoviePlayer. MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification not working.

I reference this article：
[[How to get an error description when playback fails on MPMoviePlayerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352870/how-to-get-an-error-description-when-playback-fails-on-mpmovieplayercontroller][1])
but iOS8 doesn't work.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(MPFinished: ) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:self.MoviePlayer];
```

How to do that can solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: You can use `MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification` i think that will probably solve your problem

Comment: I have this same problem. I believe it is an iOS 8 bug. I added a 5 second timer and if the video does not start playing before that hits I show an error and get out. This is a terrible hack but the only solution I currently have.

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue and the only solution I found was to replace the MPMoviePlayerController by a AVPlayerViewController (available since iOS 8 in the AVKit framework).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the "object" parameter is of class MPMoviePlayerController and not MPMoviePlayerViewController.

If self.MoviePlayer is a MPMoviePlayerViewController, just change this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(MPFinished:)
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object:self.MoviePlayer];
```

to this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(MPFinished:) 
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object:self.MoviePlayer.moviePlayer];
```

The object sending the notification is **self.MoviePlayer.moviePlayer**