# ios MPMoviePlayerController detecting not found url while playing video

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, nsnotificationcenter

I have a video player which loads video from some given url and plays. Whenever resource at given url is not valid and server returns error code with error response, I am not able to get any callback for the same. I have subscribed to following notifications.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlaybackStateDidChange:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieFinished:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:self.playerController];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieDurationAvailable:) name:MPMovieDurationAvailableNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieLoadStateDidChange:) name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(willChangePlayingMovie:) name:MPMoviePlayerNowPlayingMovieDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

I am playing video with hls video. My media have hls and mp4 url. whenever hls video fails, i wanted to fallback to mp4.

EDIT:
Just to clarify, not getting callback means notification is not firing. sorry for confusion.

Code snippet on viewdidload

```
self.playerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
self.playerController.shouldAutoplay = YES;
self.playerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;

[self.playerController.view setFrame:self.playerView.bounds];
self.playerController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[self.playerController.view translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints];



[self.playerView addSubview:self.playerController.view];
self.playerController.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
self.playerController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.2 green:0.2 blue:0.2 alpha:1.0];
self.playerController.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.2 green:0.2 blue:0.2 alpha:1.0];
//To hide top and bottom Bar

self.playerController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.playerController.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

while setting url (from viewdidappear, notification also added here, code for that is in beginning)

```
NSURL *fileUrl;
NSString *fileExtension;
fileUrl = self.content.media.hlsUrl;
if ([Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection].isReachable) {
            [self.playerController setContentURL:fileUrl];

            BOOL isFirstTimeUpdate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"IS_FIRST_TIME_UPDATE"];
            if(isFirstTimeUpdate == NO){
                [self.playerController pause];
            }
            else{
                [self.playerController play];
            }
            [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
        }else{
            self.errorLabel.text = kZErNoInternet;
            self.errorView.hidden = NO;
        }
```

Comment: can you show me some of your code? especially about when you load the url.

Comment: Just a quick one: when do you add set the notification? Before or after creating/re-creating the self.playerController instance?

Comment: about file url, i have a question, that's a local file or remote file? FYI, local file need to use "fileURLWithString", not "urlWithString"

Comment: it is remote url. Video plays successfully if given url returns valid video. however if server returns 404 or 500, i do not get any notification.

Answer (score 0):

**Handle error code with error response with  MPMoviePlayerViewController:-**

*As you have already added this notification*

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieFinished:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:self.playerController];
```

---

```
 (void)movieFinished:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *notificationUserInfo = [notification userInfo];
    NSNumber *resultValue = [notificationUserInfo objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey];
    MPMovieFinishReason reason = [resultValue intValue];
    if (reason == MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackError)
    {
        NSError *mediaPlayerError = [notificationUserInfo objectForKey:@"error"];
        if (mediaPlayerError) 
        {
            NSLog(@"playback failed with error description: %@", [mediaPlayerError localizedDescription]);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"playback failed without any given reason");
        }
    }
}
```

Just got reference from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352870/how-to-get-an-error-description-when-playback-fails-on-mpmovieplayercontroller):-

Comment: The problem is that this call back is not being called.

Comment: Then you must  describe the question on that manner, you said this "- Whenever resource at given url is not valid and server returns error code with error response ,I am not able to get any callback for the same",

Comment: U have not mentioned that your notification are not firing.