# why MPMoviePlayerViewController having different behavior with the same URL?

Tags: objective-c, ios8, streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller

I implemented MPMovieViewController in my app but it has a problem i.e.when i play video in player then first time it is failed to play but next time it will play successfully with the same URL. I am not able to understand this different behavior with the same URL. I copied code here which i used in my app.

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://nordenmovil.com/urrea/InstalaciondelavaboURREAbaja.mp4"];
MPMoviePlayerViewController * controller = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:fileURL];
controller.moviePlayer.movieSourceType= MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
[controller.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleDefault];
[controller.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[controller.moviePlayer play];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:controller];
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to handle the error for see what happens with your URL video (this is a tip that I founded long time ago [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5425012/4582941))

Add this for capture the end of play:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(handleMPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinish:)
                                            name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                          object:nil];
```

and this for see what happens:

```
- (void)handleMPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinish:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *notificationUserInfo = [notification userInfo];
    NSNumber *resultValue = [notificationUserInfo objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey];
    MPMovieFinishReason reason = [resultValue intValue];
    if (reason == MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackError)
    {
        NSError *mediaPlayerError = [notificationUserInfo objectForKey:@"error"];
        if (mediaPlayerError) 
        {
            NSLog(@"playback failed with error description: %@", [mediaPlayerError localizedDescription]);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"playback failed without any given reason");
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to remove the notification handler:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                              object:nil];
```

With this workaround you should know the error with your stream, I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I got the error
error = "Error Domain=MediaPlayerErrorDomain Code=-11800 \"The operation could not be completed\" when i am  playing video from URL
and error = "Error Domain=MediaPlayerErrorDomain Code=-11819 \"Cannot Complete Action\" when playing video from Local storage

Comment: Are you trying on simulator or real device?

Comment: I am trying on iPhone and iPad both with iOS 8.1, iOS 8.2, iOS 8.3 and 8.4

Comment: Any solution on this?